# How do I efficiently search if a user has been reported on?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do I determine if the attribute value of one model exists in the attribute value of another?

I am developing an application where I would like to see if the user's name has shown up in a report. However I don't know where to begin tackling this problem. I am already using ransack as a search feature in my application for other purposes. Would I be able to use Ransack to do this?

I would imagine I would need to create some sort of method or helper in my user controller. My end goal would be to set certain css classes based on the results (i.e a check mark for seen or an 'x' for not seen)

Maybe in my User controller I would do something like this... but I don't think the was_seen attribute is necessary anymore now that I look at it.

```
def was_seen?
    @user.was_seen = true if Report.search(@user.name) 
end
```

Model Example (snippet)

```
User Model
  :name, String
  :was_seen, Boolean


Report Model
  :body, Text
```

End goal would be to do something like this.

```
<% if user.was_seen %>
    <li class="seen"><%= user.name %></li>
<% else %>
    <li><%= user.name %></li>
<% end %>
```

POSSIBLE SOLUTION

```
def was_seen?
  @q = Report.search(body_cont: self.name).result 
  return @q.empty? ? false : true
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

User.rb

```
def was_seen?
  Report.all.select { |r| r.body.include? self.name }.length > 0 ? true : false
end
```

Then, don't forget the full method name in your ERB:

```
<% if user.was_seen? %>
    <li class="seen"><%= user.name %></li>
<% else %>
    <li><%= user.name %></li>
<% end %>
```

This method could be slow, however, depending on the number of reports and users you have, as you will have to load all reports in the database, then search through each text field, and repeat that two step process for each user. I don't have the Jedi skills for a faster query, but this should get you moving forward for now.

Comment: Thanks for your help this is the direction I want to head in! I should have mentioned scope, this project is for a small office of maybe 100 people so performance shouldn't be an issue. Over a three month period I may only have 200 reports or so. I am trying the method you provided but it seems to always return true when it shouldnt. Any suggestions? I also had to change user.name in the model method to self.name since it was throwing an error on the view.I even changed to user.name to some secure string (i.e 'fatcat') to troubleshoot and it still returns true

Comment: `Report.all.select { |r| r.body.include? user.name } ? true : false` will fetch the entire reports table into memory and then do a search. This is bad. Do a search in your database. With ransack you can write that as: `Report.serch(body_cont: user.name).result ? true : false 
` which will translate to `    => SELECT "reports".* FROM "reports"  WHERE ("reports"."body" LIKE '%your-name%')
`

Comment: Ok, I think we are getting to a closer solution. Both of the previous suggestions always returned true which was incorrect however this seemed to work for me... Anyway thoughts? See edited original post.

Comment: Sorry! Should have been checking length, as an empty array with still return true. I've updated my code and tested it in the console. This should get you an accurate true/false. Hopefully you can make this work with the more efficient Ransack.

Comment: Awesome great work thank you! I made a combination of both your suggestions and used Ransack to create a solution. Thank you for helping me today. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of task I'd recommend using a full text search engine such as [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/). There's an excellent gem called [sunspot](http://sunspot.github.io/) for interfacing with it from rails.

Solr is capable of doing much more than simple substring searches, but it's super fast even for trivial cases like this.